# How to get all the end nodes of chrome bookmark tree?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mootools1.2

I have been trying get all the bookmarked urls in chorme to the extension i am making. But till now i have only managed to get the tree, and its a very lengthy task to check where all the folders are and getting urls from them. Is there any method using which i can get all the end nodes (which would be urls) all together? I am using mootools framework.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach it:

```
function collectLinks( bookmark , bag )
{ 
  if( bookmark.children)
  { 
    for(var i = 0; i < bookmark.children.length ; i++ ) 
      collectLinks( bookmark.children[i] , bag ) 
  } 
  if(bookmark.url)bag.push(bookmark) 
}
```

This function iterates over a bookmark node ad infinitum

```
var list = [];
chrome.bookmarks.getTree( function(bookmarks){ collectLinks( bookmarks[0] , list ); collectLinks( bookmarks[1] , list );} )
```

This will get the bookmarks and retrieve the URLs into 'list'.
On a side note, `bookmarks[0]` is the bookmark bar, `bookmarks[1]` is the 'other bookmarks'